# Custom UIKit drawing with cocos2d (2.0)?

Tags: ios, uiview, cocos2d-iphone, uikit, uibezierpath

Im trying to use custom UiViews over my cocos layers in a game I'm trying to build. When i say custom UIView i want to write and use my own drawing code inside the UIView's draw rect to create the view (using bezier paths). While i know how to add the UiView onto the screen, like so :

```
  [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:myView];
```

The drawing code inside my drawRect method doesn't seem to work!

This is how ive setup cocos2d:

```
- (void)setupCocos2D {
       director = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];
       CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]
                     pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565 //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                     depthFormat:0  //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
              preserveBackbuffer:NO
                    sharegroup:nil
                   multiSampling:YES
                 numberOfSamples:1024];
      [director setView:glView];
      [glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
      [director enableRetinaDisplay:NO];
      director.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
      [director setDisplayStats:YES];
      [director setDepthTest:YES];

      [director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

 }
```

The following is my custom drawing code inside myView's draw rect method:

```
  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
  {     //// General Declarations
       CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
       context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


      //// Color Declarations
      UIColor* defaultMidGreen_COLOR = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.231 green: 0.392 blue:  0.392 alpha: 1];
      UIColor* panelGradient_COLOR = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.231 green: 0.392 blue: 0.392 alpha: 1];
      UIColor* default_0Opacity_COLOR = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.231 green: 0.392 blue: 0.392 alpha: 0];
      UIColor* defaultDarkGreen_60Opacity_COLOR = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.231 green: 0.392 blue: 0.392 alpha: 0.6];
      UIColor* iconPlayer_Fill_COLOR = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.4 green: 0.8 blue: 0.769 alpha: 1];

      //// Gradient Declarations
     NSArray* bottom_GRADIENTColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  (id)panelGradient_COLOR.CGColor,
                                  (id)[UIColor colorWithRed: 0.231 green: 0.392 blue: 0.392 alpha: 0.5].CGColor,
                                  (id)default_0Opacity_COLOR.CGColor, nil];
    CGFloat bottom_GRADIENTLocations[] = {0, 0.55, 1};
    CGGradientRef bottom_GRADIENT = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (CFArrayRef)bottom_GRADIENTColors, bottom_GRADIENTLocations);


{
    //// panelComponent-BottomSolid Drawing
    solidPaths = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [solidPaths moveToPoint: CGPointMake(0, 110)];
    [solidPaths addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(540, 110)];
    [solidPaths addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(540, 60)];
    [solidPaths addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(0, 60)];
    [solidPaths addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(0, 110)];
    [solidPaths closePath];
    [defaultMidGreen_COLOR setFill];
    [solidPaths fill];




    //// panelComponent-BottomGradient Drawing
    gradientPaths = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [gradientPaths moveToPoint: CGPointMake(0, 2)];
    [gradientPaths addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(539, 2)];
    [gradientPaths addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(539, 60)];
    [gradientPaths addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(0, 60)];
    [gradientPaths addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(0, 2)];
    [gradientPaths closePath];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [gradientPaths addClip];




    outline = [[UIBezierPath alloc ]init];
    [outline moveToPoint: CGPointMake(1, 109)];
    [outline addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(539, 109)];
    [outline addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(539, 0)];
    [outline addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(1, 0)];
    [outline addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(1, 109)];
    [outline closePath];
    [defaultDarkGreen_60Opacity_COLOR setFill];

    [iconPlayer_Fill_COLOR setStroke];
    outline.lineWidth = 1;



     gripLines = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    [gripLines moveToPoint: CGPointMake(200, 3)];
    [gripLines addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(200, 2)];
    [gripLines addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(340, 2)];
    [gripLines addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(340, 3)];
    [gripLines addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(200, 3)];
    [gripLines closePath];
    [iconPlayer_Fill_COLOR setFill];
    [gripLines fill];

}

[solidPaths stroke];
[gripLines stroke];

[outline stroke];

//// Cleanup
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
CGGradientRelease(bottom_GRADIENT);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

}

Additional Info:

- If i try to set the backgroundColor property inside draw rect, it doesnt work. However the same works if i initialize the object with the color (in the init method)
- I think it has something to with the graphics context im trying to use and a conflict between the one I'm using and the one cocos2D is using! Not sure though!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you verified that your custom drawing works in a plain UIKit project (without cocos2d)?

Comment: Ive been messing around with changing the graphics context and i can see some drawing on screen. Maybe its because the UIKit drawing cannot use the ones created by cocos and if you see in the code i reference the 'currentGraphics ' context!
Whats the correct way to create and use a new graphics context? That might be a solution to the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a couple of hours of looking around, i got this to work.

Was using the wrong context to draw my views.

Just had to remove this line.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
```